# Creating a generic object based on a Type variable

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I need to create a generic object based on a type that is stored in a database. How can I acheive this? The code below (which won't compile) explains what I mean:

```
string typeString = GetTypeFromDatabase(key);
Type objectType = Type.GetType(typeString);

//This won't work, but you get the idea!
MyObject<objectType> myobject = new MyObject<objectType>();
```

Is it possible to do this kind of thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
Type type = typeof(MyObject<>).MakeGenericType(objectType);
object myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Also - watch out; `Type.GetType(string)` only checks the executing assembly and a few system assemblies; it doesn't scan everything. If you use an assembly-qualified-name you should be fine - otherwise you may need to get the `Assembly` first, and use `someAssembly.GetType(string)`.

Comment: Does the object that you're creating have to have a constructor that takes no arguments?

Comment: @Charlie You've probably worked this out in the intervening year, but for completeness, no, you can use other constructors with [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx)`(Type, params Object[])`.