# How can I use a dynamically typed IQueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, kendo-grid

I have an ASP.NET app that uses Kendo Grids to show data. I am trying to create a way for users to create their own Grids dynamically to show whatever data in the database they want (within limits, of course).

My problem arises because I don't know at compile time what table the user will want to query on. For similar, but static, grids I use the System.Linq.IQueryable object, like so:

```
IQueryable<v_InvCountLine> query;
query = from w in dc.v_InvCountLines
            where w.BatchNum == batchNum && w.StoreRoom == storeroom && w.Serialized == 0
            select w;

//where v_InvCountLines is the name of a database table(view).
```

I want to accomplish a similar thing, but querying a table determined by a string passed in from the user.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955331/creating-a-generic-object-based-on-a-type-variable) I've managed to create such an object, but it is of type object and so it doesn't have access to any of the methods I need to actually do the work.

```
//WOLinq is the name of a database table
Type objectType = Type.GetType("WOLinq");
Type type = typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(objectType);
object query = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Is there a way to cast `query` down to it's actual type, or some other way to dynamically select a table to query with IQueryable<>?

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about ASP.NET application with Entity Framework 6 then the best solution will be to use raw SQL queries. For example:

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType("YourAppNamespace.Models." + typeNameYouGotFromUser);
string tableName = GetTableName(entityType, _dbContext);
var sql = $"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}] WHERE " + SomeOtherConditions;

var list = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery(entityType, "SELECT * FROM Orders");
foreach (var record in list) { 
    //do whatever you need with record
}
```

Here `GetTableName` is the function you can get from [this post](https://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/)

And, of course, you can use our [EasyQuery library](https://korzh.com/easyquery) for such kind of tasks.